# Some detail for the formula used in GPUImageHighlightShadowFilter?

Tags: gpuimage

I'm trying to know some theory about the implementation of the [GPUImageHighlightShadowFilter](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/blob/master/framework/Source/GPUImageHighlightShadowFilter.m) filter.
Someone can help me to find. How are the shadows and highlights calculated and what other formulas can be performed?

Answer (score 3):

Well, all the shader code for this filter is right at the top of that file:

```
uniform lowp float shadows;
uniform lowp float highlights;

const mediump vec3 luminanceWeighting = vec3(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);

void main()
{
    lowp vec4 source = texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate);
    mediump float luminance = dot(source.rgb, luminanceWeighting);

    mediump float shadow = clamp((pow(luminance, 1.0/(shadows+1.0)) + (-0.76)*pow(luminance, 2.0/(shadows+1.0))) - luminance, 0.0, 1.0);
    mediump float highlight = clamp((1.0 - (pow(1.0-luminance, 1.0/(2.0-highlights)) + (-0.8)*pow(1.0-luminance, 2.0/(2.0-highlights)))) - luminance, -1.0, 0.0);
    lowp vec3 result = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0) + ((luminance + shadow + highlight) - 0.0) * ((source.rgb - vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0))/(luminance - 0.0));

    gl_FragColor = vec4(result.rgb, source.a);
}
```

`source` is an RGBA vector containing the 0.0-1.0 values for the red, green, blue, and alpha channels. `luminance` is the 0.0-1.0 luminance of the pixel, calculated via a standard color weighting.

From there, the `shadow` and `highlight` values are calculated via the equations described on the next line (which I believe were sourced from an Adobe standard). These are then used to weight the overall brightness of that pixel to produce the `result` color.

You can easily write your own modified version of this by replicating this class and tweaking the shader calculations.

Comment: Very useful thank you. I will start by trying this color weighting luminanceWeighting: vec3(0.2126, 0.7152, 0.0722) to see what happen.